# Array list implementation using generics where the maximum size of the list is dynamic

Tags: java, arrays, generics, dynamic, console

I want to ask if someone knows how to fix this.
I am getting this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Main.add(Main.java:40)  // it is for: myList[actSize++] = object;
    at Main.main(Main.java:127) //it is for: ob.add(str+str1+str2);
```

I want to ask if what i am doing is right. I would like to build a programm that uses generics with the following: methods add,remove,get,contains and size. But when I built the program I found out that the generics cannot create an array, so I used from another post in this site: [How to: generic array creation and used the weak typing (unchecked). So the main theme of this program is someone to type in console his first name last and his phone number and then to put it in array of generics so I could save it into an object and then into a specific position. After that the program dynamically increases the threshold in order for the user to have a lot of contacts. Then he wil be told if his contact has been duplicated and it will be removed immediatly. After he will be asked if he want to remove a contract and then the program stats all over, until the user finishes his job(adding contracts).

I would be glad to hear some opinions.

(I am sorry for my English if I am not understandable.)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main < T >
{

    private Object[] myList;
    public static int actSize = 0;

    public Main(int s)
    {
        myList = new Object[s];
    }

    public T Array(int i)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final T t = (T) myList[i];
        return t;
    }

    public void add(T object) //end
    {
        if (myList.length - actSize <= 5)
        {
            myList = Arrays.copyOf(myList, myList.length * 2);
            System.out.println("\nNew length: " + myList.length);
        }

        myList[actSize++] = object;
    }

    public void add(T object, int position) //end
    {
        myList[position++] = object;
    }

    public boolean remove(T object) //end
    {
        if (myList[actSize].equals(object))
        {
            myList[actSize] = myList[actSize - 1];
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void remove(int position) //end
    {
        myList[position] = myList[position - 1];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T get(int index) //end
    {
        if (index < actSize)
        {
            return (T) myList[index];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(T object) //end
    {
        if (myList[actSize].equals(object))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            myList[actSize] = myList[actSize - 1];

        return true;
    }

    public int size() //end
    {
        return actSize;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Main ob = new Main(actSize);
        String str, str1, str2;

        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));

            while (true)
            {
                System.out.print("Do you want to add a contact? press any key to continue or n to exit :");
                String str5 = br.readLine();

                if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(str5))
                {
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                System.out.print("Enter your First Name :");
                str = br.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter your Last Name :");
                str1 = br.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter your Phone Number :");
                str2 = br.readLine();

                ob.add(str + str1 + str2);
                ob.add(str + str1 + str2, actSize);

                if (ob.contains(str + str1 + str2) == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("The contact you entered is duplicated");
                    ob.remove(ob.contains(str + str1 + str2));
                    System.out.println("The contact has been removed");
                }

                System.out.print("Do you want to add contracts? press y to continue :");
                String str3 = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("You just entered:" + str3);

                if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(str3))
                {
                    System.out.print("Which contract do you wish to be removed?");
                    String str4 = br.readLine();

                    if (str4.equals(actSize))
                    {
                        ob.remove(actSize);
                        System.out.println("The contact has been deleted.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use `java.util.ArrayList` class?

Comment: I had already, but I always took the same mistake about generic T that I cannot use generic array. I don't know maybe i haven't try it yet. Maybe can you show me in a code how to use it? or maybe sent me a link?

Comment: You are basically rewriting ArrayList (a List implementation backed by an array.). I suggest you take a look at the actual code of this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using `List<YourGenericType> list = new ArrayList<YourGenericType>();`
now you can call  `list.size(); list.add(); list.set(); list.get();...`. Also ArrayList have a dynamic size.

I suggest something like this: delete your Main and change your main method to something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String str, str1, str2;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            while (true) {

                System.out
                        .print("Do you want to add a contact? press any key to continue or n to exit :");
                String str5 = br.readLine();

                if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(str5)) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                System.out.print("Enter your First Name :");
                str = br.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter your Last Name :");
                str1 = br.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter your Phone Number :");
                str2 = br.readLine();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(str + str1 + str2);

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    String s = list.get(i);
                    if (s.equals(sb.toString())) {
                        System.out.println("Duplicate");
                        list.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                list.add(sb.toString());

                System.out
                        .print("Do you want to add contracts? press y to continue :");
                String str3 = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("You just entered:" + str3);

                if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(str3)) {
                    System.out
                            .print("Which contract do you wish to be removed?");
                    String str4 = br.readLine();

                    int index = Integer.parseInt(str4);
                    if (index < list.size() && index > 0) {
                        list.remove(index);
                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that:
 List list = new ArrayList();
 methods
main()
list.set
list.get

because i do not understand how to do it.
can you send me a link? or maybe a little program for a start?

Comment: I would love to but instead of List<String> can I use 
List<T>?

Comment: of course you can do that :) i also updated my answer so you got your program running with my changes. i also added the person after checking for duplicate since it will always say its a duplicate when it is added before. just have a look at my solution for you, and if you want to change string to <T> you will be fine too

Comment: Thank you very much dehlen. But I just read that I have to keep all the methods in my project.. Can I maybe have the methods inside the main method in order to use them somehow? I am thinking maybe and the answer that whoAmI gave me. To have a number and cause of my program to double the threshold so it can be dynamic.

Comment: not quite sure what you try to achieve now. can you clear up things a little bit ?

Comment: For the first part i wanted to make the methods about the Main class in order to add,remove,size a dynamic array list with generics.
The second part is to write a main program in order to use the above array list with the methods in order to add contacts then to remove if user wants it. So that's why I want to use them. Is it more clear now? or maybe you want more information?

Comment: in this case you will have 2 options. create the arraylist in main and call the right methods in your own methods or use an array like you did until now and correct the mistakes your code still got. But then the array could not be dynamic since you initialize the array with a fixed size once.

Comment: So for your first option I have to do the code as you do and I understand. But when you are saying call the right methods in my methods you mean:

 public void add (T object, int position) //end
 {        
  add(); 
 } 

I am really sorry if I am annoying, but I want to learn some things.

Comment: yeah add methods would be like `private void add(T object) { myList.add(object); }` But it is not very suggestive. But if you have to do it like that...

Comment: If it's not very suggestive then, the other solution I think is your program, isn't it?

Comment: right why would you implement a different class which just calls the methods of arraylist when you can call the methods of arraylist directly without implementing an own class with own methods

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `List` to store unknown amount of data.

For your code:

```
myList[actSize++] = object;
```

throws exception because `myList` is initialized with `0` length. So you cannot put anything in index 0.

Comment: Maybe if I change the method Main and instead of s, to put a number will be able to do the trick?

Comment: It can help. But if you put a number and try to put more elemnts than the number, you'll get the problem again.